# Manage Partition Key in Azure Cosmos DB with C# SDK

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Is there any way to manage an Azure Cosmos DB collection *with partition key* that uses the Mongo API directly from c#?

Currently we use Terraform to provision the Cosmos DB account and the database and we use the [MongoDB.Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver) to administrate collections. To get the Collection (and create it if it does not exist), we use the following syntax:

```
public IMongoCollection<MyDocument> MyDocumentsCollection =>
             Database.GetCollection<MyDocument>("MyDocuments", mongoCollectionSetting);
```

I do not see any option to set the partition key for the collection and I was expecting to accomplish this with the mongoCollectionSettings. What is the best option to get this working?

I have found the [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3) but this is only applicable for Cosmos DB's SQL API.

I have tried to use the method [RunCommand](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.16/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_RunCommand.htm) as described [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/how-to-create-container) but the code

```
var bson = new BsonDocument
{
    { "customAction", "CreateCollection" },
    { "collection", "<CollectionName>" },//update CollectionName
    { "shardKey", "<ShardKeyName>" }, //update ShardKey
    { "offerThroughput", 400} //update Throughput
};
var shellCommand = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(bson);
// Create a collection with a partition key by using Mongo Driver:
db.RunCommand(shellCommand);
```

throws the error "Invalid index key specified" when working against a local Mongo DB docker container.

[image]

While the "customAction" does not throw any error when run against the Cosmos Server and the collection is also created, I do not see that the partition key is generated correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "manage partition key"? Can you please edit your question to include some sample data, relevant code, etc?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have included the code snippet that shows how we currently create new and access existing collections. Does that clarify things for you? I am new to document databases and maybe I am also approaching this from the completely wrong direction?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/custom-commands#create-collection

Comment: Sorry for the silence, and thank you all for your input so far. I was on holidays and had this problem waiting. The link shared by @Rikita made me accept that I will have to work with RunCommand. However things do not work as laid out in the documentation. I have updated my initial post with this information and I am happy te reveive further help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way to create shard collection is with `RunCommand()`. However, we can use the below work around to catch the exception thrown by `RunCommand()`. If the collection already exists and we can use the `GetCollection()` from azure cosmosdb-mongoApi in the catch block to perform additional operations on the existing shard collection.

**Note:-** If you want to update the shardkey or partionkey, you will have to delete the collection and recreate it with new shardkey.

As you are already aware, still sharing [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/how-to-create-container) documentation has the details of creating new shard collection using `RunCommand()`.
As mentioned above, the work around to create sharded collection using the `RunCommand()`is as explained below:

The `RunCommand()` method as known doesn't check if collection exists or not and throws exception if collection already exists.
Hence, by implementing exception handling we can achieve the desired result. In try block we can call the `RunCommand()`. If the collection is not present then RunCommand will create a shard collection. If the collection already exists then exception will be thrown in the try block and will be caught by catch block. In catch block we can use `GetCollection()`to get the existing collection details and perform further operations on the existing collection.
This ensures that we only create new shard collections and update existing shard collections.
Below is code snippet for the same.

```
try  
{  
db.RunCommand(shellCommand);  
}  
catch(Exception ex)  
{  
var _products = db.GetCollection<Product>("col4");  
products.InsertOne(new Product(  
Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),  
"test1",  
"test2",  
12,  
false  
));  
Console.WriteLine("item Created");  
}
```